# Модуль работает неправильно

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, модули

На данный момент занимаюсь созданием своего собственного модуля по поиску файлов  с указанными форматами в введенных директориях. То есть, пользователь вводит директорию и формат для поиска('.jpg', '.txt', '.dll' etc) Однако в коде возникла проблема.
Мой код:

```
 import sys
 import os


 def walker(directory, format):
     for name in os.listdir(directory):
         path = os.path.join(directory, name)
         check = os.path.basename(path)
         if os.path.isfile(path):
            if format in check:
               print([path])
         else: walker(path, format)

 walker('C://Users/Admin/Desktop', '.jpg')
```

Проблема в том что при команде запуска модуля в другом файле...

```
  import module
  path = 'C://......'
  format = '.jpg'
  module.walker(path, format)
```

функция сначала принимает аргументом исходный путь, а потом только уже введенный юзером. Получается, выводится 2 разных результата. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как можно это исправить?

Comment: Правильно он работает :)

Comment: Да я знаю, что правильно, просто я думал модуль при импорте не заработает, потому что не выполнено условие) Как Вы думаете, данный модуль стоит выкладывать на GitHub, или же еще потренировать свои способности и улучшить кодстайл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас в исходном коде есть следующая строка:

```py
walker('C://Users/Admin/Desktop', '.jpg')
```

При импорте модуля исполняется весь код этого модуля, то есть и строка выше.

Чтобы этого избежать, можно сделать проверку на то, импортируется ли модуль.
Добавьте в Ваш исходный код следующие инструкции:

```py
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    walker('C://Users/Admin/Desktop', '.jpg')
```